# Multilevel XML to CSV XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, transform

I've been working on an XML to CSV transformation and I've been using the following XSLT doc for the transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:variable name="delimiter" select="','"/>
  <xsl:key name="field" match="/*/*/*" use="local-name()"/>
  <xsl:variable name="allFields" select="/*/*/*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('field', local-name())[1])]"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
      <xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*"/>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="this" select="."/>
    <xsl:for-each select="$allFields">
      <xsl:value-of select="$this/*[local-name() = local-name(current())]"/>
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; last()">
        <xsl:value-of select="$delimiter"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:text/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I run the transformation on the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Calls>
  <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
    <CustomerID>000391</CustomerID>
    <Filter1>1</Filter1> <Filter2>1</Filter2> 
  </Call>
  <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
    <CustomerID>000528</CustomerID>
    <Filter1>1</Filter1> <Filter2>1</Filter2> 
  </Call>
</Calls>
```

The transformation works fine and I get the following result:

```
CustomerID,Filter1,Filter2
000391,1,1
000528,1,1
```

However if I add an additional level to the children, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Calls>
  <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
    <CustomerID>000391</CustomerID>
    <Filter1><AA>A</AA><BB>B</BB></Filter1>
  </Call>
  <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
    <CustomerID>000528</CustomerID>        
    <Filter1>1</Filter1> <Filter2>1</Filter2> 
  </Call>
</Calls>
```

I get the following output:

```
CustomerID,Filter1,Filter2
000391,AB,
000528,1,1
```

I want it to be:

```
CustomerID,Filter1,AA,BB,Filter2 
000391,<FILTER1 VALUE>,A,B 
000528,1,<AA VALUE>,<BB VALUE>,1
```

The problem occurs no matter how many levels I end up adding. What I want is for all the child names and the values to be presented in a CSV fashion.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What would be the expected result in your example?

Comment: Just taking a look at your xslt, it looks like you have hard-coded 3 levels into your solution "/*/*/*"

Comment: A CSV file is basically a two dimensional structure with lines and columns. So you can canonically map to a two layer XML structure as you did.  The third level (or any other additional level) will be more difficult since you will have to define the additional mapping. Which leads to @michael.hor257k's remark... One way to do it would be to define a quoted field by using e.g. double quotes bracing the contents of the third level.

Comment: I want the name of the lowe level children names be written as headers and the appropriate values to be displayed under them

Comment: Should in the example provided AA and BB be written as headers with values A and B for 1st call and empty values for 2nd call or is the required result for 1st call filter1 value something like e.g. (AA: A, BB: B) or else? It's just not 100% clear if AA and BB are low level children or kind of a special value for filter1.

Comment: AA and BB not a special values for Filter1 but a children of it, however the don't always appear. Edited the question to show the desired result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, this is not at all simple. I would suggest you abandon the attempt at a totally generic approach and concentrate on a more custom-tailored solution - although still flexible enough to accommodate multiple levels as they come.

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns0="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="/Calls/ns0:Call//*" use="local-name()" />
<xsl:key name="cell" match="/Calls/ns0:Call//*" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::ns0:Call), '|', local-name())" />
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- unique column names -->
    <xsl:variable name="columns">
        <xsl:for-each select="Calls/ns0:Call//*[count(. | key('element-by-name', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
            <column><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></column>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($columns)/column">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    <!-- rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="Calls/ns0:Call">
        <xsl:variable name="row-id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($columns)/column">
            <xsl:variable name="col" select="." />
            <!-- switch context back to document -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$root">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('cell', concat($row-id, '|', $col))/text()"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to the following **input**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Calls>
    <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
        <CustomerID>001</CustomerID>
        <Filter1>
            <AA>aa</AA>
            <BB>bb</BB>
        </Filter1>
        <Filter2>f2</Filter2> 
    </Call>
    <Call xmlns="urn:eas-samples:en:xsd:phonecalls.1.0">
        <CustomerID>002</CustomerID>        
        <Filter1>f1</Filter1> 
        <Filter2>f2</Filter2> 
        <Filter3>f3</Filter3> 
    </Call>
</Calls>
```

will return:

```
CustomerID,Filter1,AA,BB,Filter2,Filter3
001,,aa,bb,f2,
002,f1,,,f2,f3
```

---

### Edit:

If you don't know the element names, but do know that the "rows" are always at the second level, i.e. `/*/*`, then you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:key name="element-by-name" match="/*/*//*" use="local-name()" />
<xsl:key name="cell" match="/*/*//*" use="concat(generate-id(ancestor::*[last()-1]), '|', local-name())" />
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/" />

<xsl:template match="/">

    <!-- unique column names -->
    <xsl:variable name="columns">
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*//*[count(. | key('element-by-name', local-name())[1]) = 1]">
            <column><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></column>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- header -->
    <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($columns)/column">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>

    <!-- rows -->
    <xsl:for-each select="*/*">
        <xsl:variable name="row-id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="exsl:node-set($columns)/column">
            <xsl:variable name="col" select="." />
            <!-- switch context back to document -->
            <xsl:for-each select="$root">
                <xsl:value-of select="key('cell', concat($row-id, '|', $col))/text()"/>
            </xsl:for-each> 
            <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each> 
        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Michael,

Thanks for the offer problem is i don't know what the root of the document is I only know the child path.

So the following line: Calls/ns0:Call can't be used

Comment: @jonatzin You *can* use `*` instead of an element whose name you don't know. But you **must** know at what level the "rows" are.

Comment: Yes I do know what level the rows are, I'll test it and let you know